# How do I select a subset of the available fonts for a particular application

Tags: fonts, libreoffice, abiword

Having all those exotic fonts (for an European), like Chinese, Hindi or Russian fonts, is nice for a web browser. You never get those ugly unicode blocks and get the original glyphs instead. However, having the font menu in LibreOffice or AbiWord populated with all of those fonts is cumbersome and useless for most installations. Having more than a few fonts in note taking applications is also somewhat overkill.

Is there a way I can designate a subset of all the available fonts to work with a particular application? I understand the app itself could do it, but I'm asking for a way to make LibreOffice, for instance, not see certain fonts, only my selection of "useful for text processing" subset.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. Unaccepted answer or unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Flagged for deletion. Thanks!